# get a wrong next month in PHP

Tags: php, date

Today is **31<sup>st</sup> May**

```
$currentM = date('m');
// 05

$nextM = date('m', strtotime('+1 month'));
// 07
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why the next month is giving `07`.

Comment: Define how "+1 month" *should* work first. You'll find it's kind of a tough definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The next month from today (31/5) is the 31/6 which doesn't exist, so it forwards to the 1/7.

You may want to increment the actual month: `$nextM = date('m') % 12 + 1`

Comment: Try to use `$currentM = date('m'); $nextM = $currentM+1` works for me

Comment: kind of laughed a bit

Comment: if `date('m')` is `12` ?

Comment: @l2aelba the may is the fifth month?

Comment: That is !!!!!  31/6 doesn't exist so 1/7 , I understand now ! Damm me !

Comment: @l2aelba today is 31/05 in the UK, though I know there are parts of the world where it's 30/05, and some where it's already 1/06

Comment: This answer is wrong though. Because just incrementing the month with 1 will produce 13 when in Decembre.

Comment: @MarkBaker He wrote in his question that today is the 31/5?

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify('first day of next month');
echo $d->format('m');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following snippets,

```
$month = date('n') % 12 + 1;
```

(OR)

```
$month = date('m', strtotime('+1 months'));
```

(OR)

```
$month = date('m') + 1
```

Comment: The second one did specifically *not* work, the third one will eventually give you "13".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that today is the 31st. Adding a month may overlap 2 months.

I usually simply solve this by using day 1 to add a month and using day 28 to substract a month:

```
 echo(date('m'));
 echo "\n";
 echo(date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m-28') . ' -1 month'))); // day 28 - 1 month
 echo "\n";
 echo(date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m-1') . ' +1 month'))); // day 1 + 1 month
```

Output:

```
05
04
06
```